# Understanding CoreData using relationship

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, core-data, entity-relationship

I'm having a misunderstanding using **CoreData** and **relationship**.

What i remember from my sql's time ( long time ago... ) i have to add and ***ID*** to each tables which will be the entry which make relation between tables.

Below the overview of what my tables looks like in my `CoreData` (entities).

`Epro_Sheet` is my **main table**, the others have to be related to that one.

What i want to do is that :

- The user fills fields on a UIViewController (`EPro_CompanyViewController`) which has his own Entity `EPro_Company`
- Then when he press next - that create `EPro_Sheet`, increment idSheet and fill the others entries - moreover the `EPro_Company` are filled with the fields text of the EPro_CompanyViewController.
- Then the user will fill up fields of `EPro_DaFroidViewController`, then when he press next it fill the entity EPro_DaFroid get the current Id of the current EPro_Sheet and set it to EPro_DaFroid...
- Etc....
- There will be a UIViewController ( History ) which allows the user to retrieve all information of a specific date to either edit it or display it.

Could you help me on the way how to do it ? relationship or not at all ... if there is relationship how can i retrieve information using a NSPredicateFormat like : retrieve me all information from the date @" .... ";

thanks a lot for any help !

[image]

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: Yes. As MVP said, Explain your query short and clear then only u will get quick response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to understand that core-data is not a relational database and the concept of primary key etc is not there. It's left to you for implementation. More details on this can be found here :

[Core-data vs RDBMS](http://robnapier.net/blog/core-data-rdbms-11)

and here

[The differences between Core Data and a Database](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)

If you have want to implement relationship in core-data you have to create a relationship in the core-data model. Imagine you have relationship like this:

Student <->> Section

i.e one student belongs to one section and one section can have many students. Then in your core-data model you can define a relationship  (say `oneSection`) from Student to Section that is one-to-one and another relationship(say `manyStudents`) from Section to Student that is one-to-many. And then you set the relationship as the inverse relationship of each other.

Although we declare this as relationship , it pretty much acts as a property of the managed object.

So if you have an managed objects called `studObj1` and `studObj2` (`Student` Entity), then you set the relationship like this to a section object (`sectionObj`):

(assuming you will be creating a managed object subclass)

```
Student *studObj1= <create object>
Student *studObj2= <create object>

Section *sectionObj = <create object>

//set one-to-one relationship
studObj1.oneSection = sectionObj;
studObj2.oneSection = sectionObj;

//set one-to-many relationship;

NSSet *studSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:studObj1,studObj2,nil];
sectionObj.manyStudents = studSet;
```

Regarding predicate you can use the properties of the relationship directly:
ie. if you want to get students based on section you can create a predicate like the following:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"oneSection.name like 'MainSection'"];
```